# Humorous limerick on Cirencester / virencester / explirencester. I don't get it

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

According to the [English Language Wikipedia page on Cirencester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirencester#Pronunciation), Cirencester has many pronunciations.  From Wikipedia:

The form /ˈsɪsɪtər/, spelled Cirencester or Ciceter, was once used locally. This pronunciation is humorously highlighted in a 1928 limerick from Punch:

```
There was a young lady of Cirencester
Whose fiancé went down to virencester
    By the great Western line,
    Which he swore was divine,
And he couldn't have been much explirencester.
```

I don't understand the humour in this limerick.  I think the words *virencester* and *explirencester* do not exist.  But are they variations of existing words?  Where is the humour in this?

Comment: Could you explain how this has to do with learning English? It might be better to ask this on [ELU SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @user3169 I thought it may be obvious to a native speaker but non-obvious to a non-native speaker like me.  I'm happy to have it migrated to either site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right. Those two words don't exist. They're plays on the reading of Cirencester.
Your example is roughly

> There was a young lady of /ˈsɪsɪtər/
>   Whose fiancé went down to /ˈvɪz·ɪtər/
>            By the Great Western line,
>            Which he swore was divine,
>   And he couldn't have been much /ɪkˈsplɪs.ɪtər/.
>   →
>   *There was a young lady of **Cirencester**
>
>   Whose fiancé went down to **visiter** (= visit 'er, visit her)
>
>            By the Great Western line,
>
>            Which he swore was divine,
>
>   And he couldn't have been much **expliciter**. (= more explicit)*

I interpret the final line to mean that he told a such a sexually explicit story about his visit with the young lady, that there couldn't have been a more explicit story. Of course, this is exaggeration. Therein lies the humor.

EDIT: According to @JamesK, the last would mean "he was very clear about how good the GWR was". I assumed there was a dirty angle.

Comment: Strictly it's the Great Western line (capital G, capital W). Also, I don't think all limericks are necessarily a "play" on _There once was a man from Nantucket_.

Comment: The last line would just mean "he was very clear about how good the GWR was". The euphemism is unrecorded before the 1970s

Comment: There was a young lady called Horton/ Who had one long tit and one short 'un/ 
What's more than that,/ She had a big hairy prat/ And a fart like a six-fifty Norton. NB they were prats more often than they were twats in 1962.

Comment: It's true that limericks are not _necessarily_ obscene, but that's the way it seems to go. Sometimes, of course, that's a starting point. "There was a young girl from Madras/Who had a magnificent ass./ It was not, as you think/ Round, firm and pink,/ It was grey, had long ears and ate grass."